# Using bitmask to look up used arrangements of ints in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have rarely used bitmasks and am trying to get more familiar with them. I understand various basic usages of them. As I understand them this should be able to work, but it seems to not work.

I have a use case where I have four different ints that may come in different arrangements, and I need to check if the current arrangement of ints has already come before as a different arrangement.

```
So one iteration they might come as:
2, 5, 10, 8 
Next iteration:
1, 0, 2, 5
Now on the next iteration if this comes:
0, 1, 2, 5
```

It needs to discern that last set has already come in a different arrangement and skip it.

I am wondering, can I create a mask out of these ints, put them in a HashSet, so then I have easy lookup for whether or not that set of ints has come before?

Basically I am doing this:

```
                    int mask = int0 & int1 & int2 & int3;

                    if (checkHashSet.Contains(mask))
                        return; // int set already came, skip

                    //int set has not been processed, add mask and process
                    checkHashSet.Add(mask);
```

But that seems to be producing a mask that ends up equal to all following masks generated. So this doesn't work.

Can this work like this somehow? What would be the most performant way to check if a set of ints, no matter their arrangement, has already been processed?

Comment: They are very suspicious masking values

Comment: what will happen, when one of your ints will become `2147483647`

Comment: lets say the ints will always be between 1 and 1000

Comment: Or is there some completely better way to do this?

Comment: @rygo6, I mean that bit masks works complitly different ways. For example `1 & 2 & 4 & 8` and `3 & 5 & 7 & 15` will produce exactly the same mask

Answer (score 1):

1. Bit mask is generated by shift

   ```
   int mask = (1 << int0) & (1 << int1) & (1 << int2) & (1 << int3);
   ```
2. `HashSet.Add` will check whether the item exists, `Contains` is redundant.

   ```
   if(checkHashSet.Add(mask))
       //int set has not been processed, add mask and process
   else
       // int set already came, skip
   ```
3. If the integer is greater than 31, you can use `long` or `ulong`, if it is greater than 64, then use 2 `long`s or [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my issue with syntax. But this seems to have the same issue, in that the resulting 'mask' int ends up equaling 0. So if I put that 'mask' int into a HashSet, then the following 'mask' int also equals zero and can't go into the HashSet.

Comment: It doesn't work anyway.  Take for example the input `1, 1, 1, 1` vs ,`1`.  I think it will incorrectly identify them as the same.  Once of my solutions suffers the same problem.

Comment: @rygo6, The result at least is 1.

Comment: @LoztInSpace , "_four different ints_" in the question

Comment: It's ambiguous if you consider Different vs Distinct :)  but I agree if there are no duplicates masking will work.

Answer (score 0):

To your question of "is there a better way".  I think probably yes.

1) Sort your inputs and keep a map of entries you've already seen as a string.  This is close to what you proposed but would be easier to read & implement.

2) An map having a key that is `int[1000]` would be easier than bit masks. As you process your input, for each number you find, increment the location in the array `++array[n]`.  You can then add that to a map with `array[]` as your key. You can search the map to work out if you've seen a particular combination before.

3) 1<< n only goes so far so you'd need array of ints to do it as a proper mask.  array[n / 64] & (1 << (n % 64) ) or something like that.  A good solution for embedded perhaps, but generally harder to understand.  Also, it won't work reliably if any number is repeated as bits can only only mark one occurrence.  Or use BigInteger as per Shingo's answer.

Personally I'd go the first one.

Comment: So as I understand. I cannot put an array of ints into a HashSet, then look up that int array with a different int array. I would still have to iterate over every array of ints to compare them component wise. Is there a faster way?

Comment: #2 I am suggesting `Map<int[1000],int>`.  You have to iterate your source, `++int[n]` where n is the number in your input (do this once for each input number).  When you are done, you should have an array that represents your input.  By keying in a map you can find it easily.